# How do I put a lore AND an enchantment on an item in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am someone who likes minecraft and all commands in it. except what I'm having trouble with is how to put a lore AND an enchantment on an item in minecraft.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of giving yourself an item with lore:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Lore:["text here"]}}
```

Just replace "text here" with the desired text.

This is an example of giving yourself an item with an enchantment (sharpness in this case):

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:1}]}
```

"lvl" is the level of the enchantment. I made it 1, but you could make it 2 3 4 or as high as you want.

This is an example of giving yourself a diamond sword with the lore of "shiny!" and with a knockback 3 enchantment:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Lore:["shiny!"]},Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:3}]}
```

To find a full list of possible enchantments to use, go to:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Data_values

Answer (score 3):

> **Moderator Note:** This answer appears to be outdated in newer versions of Minecraft. Please reference one of the newer answers if you're playing the latest version.

`/give @p 'custom_item' 1 0 {display{Name:"Custom Name"},Lore:["Custom lore"]},ench:[{id:'enchantmentid',lvl:'enchantmentlvl}]}`

Here is an example given: giving sword called "`Bertha`" with a lore "`she's beautiful`" with sharpness I.

`/give @p wooden_sword 1 0 {display{Name:"Bertha"},Lore:["She's beautiful"]},ench:[{id:16,lvl:1}]}`

You need to tell what item you're giving, followed by the amount. (for swords and tools more than one will stack) the second number is the damage amount. This means how much damage the item will have when it is given to you.

So, if you want a really OP bow, that has only 10 usage left, you can do `/give @p bow 1 374`

`

Comment: It's generally a good idea to explain what this is going to do, not just dump a command as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With 1.13.x the command syntax has changed.

It is now:

`/give @selector item_name{Enchantments:[{id:"enchantment_name",lvl:number}],display:{Lore:["lore_text"]}} item_amount`

For example:

`/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:5}],display:{Lore:["Excalibur!"]}} 1`

- `/give @selector amount meta item_name-or-id` has changed to `/give @selector item_name amount`
- numeric IDs no longer work, so the enchantment (and any other IDs) must be written out
- the item data is now tied directly to the item: `item_name{data, some_data{more_data},etc}`